# Is shiny Gyarados available in Pokemon Leaf Green?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I am playing Leaf green again, and I watched in anime that there is a **red** Gyarados which is said to be a shiny one. So I want to know is it **available** in Leaf-Green and how to catch it? I have encountered shiny Pokemon before but not once with Gyarados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The famous [Red Gyardos](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Red_Gyarados) is not specifically found in LeafGreen

> **In Pokémon Gold, Silver, Crystal, HeartGold and SoulSilver, the red Gyarados is found in the Lake of Rage**. The player has one chance to catch it and the incident triggers the battle against Team Rocket in the Team Rocket HQ in Mahogany Town. When captured or defeated, the red Gyarados drops a Red Scale. While this is the only chance to catch the Red Gyarados in the original games, it will respawn in the remakes after the player defeats Lance and the Elite Four, should the player fail to capture it.
>   **In Pokémon FireRed and LeafGreen,** in the Rocket Warehouse located on Five Island, one of the computers displays information about induced evolution using electromagnetic waves, **hinting at what occurs to other Gyarados in Generation II's Lake of Rage**.

Comment: So that means no shiny gyarados in LG?

Comment: @ShubhamWagh Correct, There is no shiny gyardos to run into like you could in Gen 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are shiny Pokemon in Leaf Green, so you should be able to encounter it (or a shiny Magikarp). Just keep on grinding, and make use of the usual tactics to increase your slim odds.

Answer (score -1):

Any shiny Gyarados that you can find will be red no matter what. The easiest and most common way was in generations II or IV when they appeared in the Lake of Rage as a sprite that you only had to talk to.

[image: Red Gyarados - Lake of Rage]

Comment: That's not answer to my question

Comment: Leaf Green is Generation 1 so the red gyarados will appear just like any other shiny

Comment: Leaf green is generation 3 duh

Comment: Uh... you're right (my bad), still the sprite only shows on II and IV on the others gens it's like any other shiny